# Laravel 5.2 does't working in amazon ec2

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, laravel-5, cloud-hosting

I am working on a project in my development windows environment. I tried to test my code in Amazon cloud with Ubuntu server. I installed all required stuff (Apache, php, mysql). I have also done necessary things to install and create a fresh laravel project using composer.

actually laravel working but view file does not load in any page.

Comment: that is why having problem with permission. so check the permission level of view files

Comment: how to set laravel view permission ??

Comment: try `composer dumpautoload`